# web page not available in android webview

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-layout, webview

I created a simple webview :

MainActivity.java :

```
package com.example.browser;


import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView web;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        web=findViewById(R.id.web);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.loadUrl("https://google.com");
    }
}
```

when im running it, im getting "web page not available"

i tried adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>`
in activity_main.xml but app crashes on launch

Comment: Can you change the url to https://www.google.com
add www. before google

Comment: @MuhammadSaad same error :/

Comment: Can you post the crash log from logcat here?

Answer (score 1):

Set webViewClient before load

```
web.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
```

Comment: now im getting :
        web.webViewClient = WebViewClient();
           ^
  symbol:   variable webViewClient
  location: variable web of type WebView